# How to wait for the complete execution of a loop Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have such a loop :

```
var someArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var tempArray = [];

    arangodb.query('somequery')
        .then(
            cursor => cursor.all()
        ).then(
            keys => tempArray  = keys,
            err => console.error('Failed to execute query:', err)
        ).then(function () {
            someArray.push.apply(someArray, tempArray);
        });
}
```

I want to do other operations when all `tempArrays` are collected in `someArray`. But since Node.js is async, I don't know how to do it. Can you help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: node.js isn't async, `arangodb.query` is

Comment: can `arangodb.query('somequery')` be run in parallel or do they have to be in series? also, if one fails, continue processing or stop?

Comment: They can run in parallel, if you refer to my answer Promise.all() would reject if even 1 of the promises fail

Comment: @marvel308 I was asking what the OP wanted, not what your answer does - perhaps the OP needs in series, perhaps one failure shouldn't reject the whole process - it's up to the OP, not up to your answer

Comment: @JaromandaX It does not matter if they run in parallel or in series. I just want to process the complete array. And it shouldn't stop when one fails.

Comment: yes sorry I misunderstood

Comment: Ok. That changes the code i was going to post a little

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will result in a flat array of `keys` from `cursor.all()`

any `arangodb.query` that fails will be ignored (still with console output though)

```
Promise.all(myArray.map(item => 
    arangodb.query('somequery')
    .then(cursor => cursor.all()))
    .catch(err => console.error('Failed to execute query:', err))
)
// remove rejections, which will be undefined
.then(results => results.filter(result => !!result))
// flatten the results
.then(results => [].concat(...results))
.then(results => {
    // do things with the array of results
})
```

Comment: Will this line exactly be like this : `.then(results => [].concat(...results))` ? I mean should there be  three dots?

Comment: Yes. In es2016 or is it es2017. Anyway. Latest node will like it. Use babel otherwise

Comment: Thank you, one last question : in the last part should it be like this : `.then(results => {
    someArray = results;
})` Or should there be some other code as well?

Comment: Why. You can't access the data synchronously

Comment: I was asking if the result is the array that I want.

Comment: Should be. I can't test for you

Comment: @jason, yes the result is what you want, but you can't use it outside this function *(or a function invoked by this function)* because of time. This task is async; you don't know when this function is called and therefore when the `result` is available. For you this might be just a few milliseconds, but JS can run a lot of code in that time.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for your explanation. So I must write lots of `.then` to work with query results all the time, right?

Comment: @jason Get a different perspective. You are dealing with values that will eventually be there but you have no clue when. With promises you can write a simple `.then()` instead of having to manange the state on your own *(is the value available? is it still loading? did it throw?)*. Instead of looking at the additional `then()`s you have to write, look at the work it does so you don't have to; and how it cleans up your code. Maybe you want to look up the term `callback hell`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
var someArray = [];

function queryDB(){
    return arangodb.query('somequery')
        .then(
            cursor => cursor.all()).then(
            keys => tempArray  = keys,
            err => console.error('Failed to execute query:', err)
         ).catch(function(err){
            console.log('Failed');
         })
}
var promiseArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
   promiseArray.push(queryDB());
} 

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(results){

    someArray = results.filter(result => !!result);
})
```

basically queryDB() would return a promise, you can do Promise.all() to wait for all promises to resolve and then you can access the result in result

Comment: This won't work for failures and might signal early completion falsely. Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Promise.all fail-fast behaviour

Promise.all is rejected if any of the elements are rejected. For example, if you pass in four promises that resolve after a timeout and one promise that rejects immediately, then Promise.all will reject immediately.

Comment: `tempArray` is undefined, your result would be a array of arrays - you've rewritten too much of the OP's intent

Comment: @ManasJayanth so should I pass to `someArray` after each promise?

Comment: @ManasJayanth it wasn't clear in the question, Promise.all() would only resolve if each of the promises resolved and would do so in parallel if it need to be done serially try http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.each.html

Comment: @marvel308 You are overlooking cases where some of the tasks fail. `Promise.all` fails immediately when even one of the tasks fail.

Bluebird's docs speak only for their library - which hopefully is spec compliant

Comment: @ManasJayanth and you are overlooking the `catch` that ensures that no Error reaches `Promise.all()`, it's here: `.then(keys => ..., err => console.error(...))`

Comment: That was the corrected code sorry, I wasn't catching before

Comment: Yes, such a promise would always resolve. Corrected version would work.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to track if all your async operations are complete or not is to simply keep count of success callback triggers and failure callback triggers. Following should help you out.

```
let count = 0;

const checkCompletion = (curr, total) => {
    if (curr < total) {
        // Not all tasks finised
    } else {
        // All done
    }
};

for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    var   tempArray = [];
    arangodb.query('somequery')
        .then(cursor => cursor.all())
        .then(keys => {
            // success
            count += 1;
            checkCompletion(count, myArray.length);
        }).catch(e => {
            // failure
            count += 1;
            checkCompletion(count, myArray.length);
        });

}
```